# How to enable only a part of TextInput in react-Native?

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have a text input component in React-native with which I am showing some text by default and user should not be able to edit it. He should keep continue to type in that. Like this:
[image]

Comment: You can have two TextInput placed adjacently with one `editable={false}`

Comment: Is the above approach works fine for you?

Comment: It might work. But I am looking for a more reliable solution where I can manage it with only one text field